# Quantum Quench Problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, cold-atoms

I read about the quantum quench problem in condensed matter physics.
But what does really mean? Has anybody a good explanation about the origin of quantum quench problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you mean to ask, but what I know as a quantum quench is a sudden change in the potential, sufficiently fast that it can be considered instantaneous. In that case the state doesn't change instantaneously, but obviously its time evolution does: from that point it evolves according to the new Hamiltonian. If originally you were in an eigenstate, generally you will be in a superposition of states for the new Hamiltonian after the quench.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "Quantum Quench" with Google, found http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~eyuzbash/papers/PhysRevLett_105_135701.pdf (PDF link, but freely available) and looked at the first paragraph and found

> The shattering of cold glass in hot water is but one of
>   many spectacular effects that can be induced by a rapid
>   thermal quench in classical media. What happens when an
>   isolated quantum phase of matter is subject to **a sudden,
>   violent deformation of its system Hamiltonian (a ‘‘quantum
>   quench’’)**?

(emphasis added)

Now, that is not a lot of detail, but it sets the stage. Further, it is the kind of thing that you should have been able to find yourself before asking here.